# (Multiple Select) Arrange options depends on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Does anyone know how to do in **JQuery** and get the selected options by order depends on the user selection?

```
    <select class="form-control" name="cols[]" multiple="multiple" id="cols[]" required="required">
                        <option value="latest_upd">Latest Update</option>
                        <option value="status">Status</option>
                        <option value="spin">SPIN</option>
                        <option value="file_location">File location</option>
                        <option value="upl_webgis">uploaded to webgis</option>
                        <option value="rem_upl">Remarks on upload</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: you just have set selected attribute in option tag. Eg : <option value="latest_upd" selected>Latest Update</option>

Comment: what i want is to get the selected options depends on user selection

Comment: i write my answer : using php and jquery both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :** Using PHP and Jquery both

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<pre>",print_r($_POST,1),"</pre>";
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" name="cols[]" multiple="multiple" id="cols[]" required="required">
      <option value="latest_upd">Latest Update</option>
      <option value="status">Status</option>
      <option value="spin">SPIN</option>
      <option value="file_location">File location</option>
      <option value="upl_webgis">uploaded to webgis</option>
      <option value="rem_upl">Remarks on upload</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit',function() {
        var result = '';
      $('select[name="cols[]"]').find('option:selected').each(function() {
         result = $('select[name="cols[]"]').val();
      });
      alert(result);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```